# Are more than one correct Lewis structures possible (not counting resonance)?

Tags: lewis-structure

I am currently learning chemical bonding, specifically Lewis structures. And these nitrogen oxides, nitrogen-oxygen ions and other atoms showing variable oxidation states are confusing me. As many examples I have understood with bonding atoms having no $d$ or $f$ orbitals, the variable oxidation states are a result of dative bonds.

So when drawing the Lewis structure for $\ce{NO3-}$, I drew:

[image: Nitrate ion - my structure]

My book however has only one dative bond, and has this structure:

[image: Nitrate ion - book's structure]

To me, both of them look correct. The octets seem to be satisfied in both cases.

So my questions are:

1. Are both of them correct? If yes, how?
2. If my structure is incorrect, what rule am I violating?

Comment: nitrogen can make 3 covalent bond and has one lone pair so 1 lone pair will be distributed to 1 oxygen and then nitrogen will form 1 double bond with another oxygen now nitrogen can form only one single bond which will be possible with oxygen having negative sign just like the second structure in your question

Comment: @shashanksharma You are explaining the correctness of the structure in the book, which I know is correct. I am asking what's wrong with my structure? It too satisfies the octet.

Comment: your questions says to draw a lewis structure of n o 3 - but in your  structure you showed negative sign in nitrogen which is not mentioned in question.

Comment: @shashanksharma what do you mean by "not mentioned in the question"? I had to draw the structure for $\ce{NO3-}$, I drew it by assigning negative charge on N, in the book it is drawn by assigning negative charge on one of the O atoms. I am simply asking if my approach is correct or not? And if not, then why?

Comment: @swapnil you have to note that nitrate is an **ion**. So, the negative charge on one of the O atoms is simply demonstrating the existence of an extra negative charge, *not* the existence of a second dative bond.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani I drew the first structure myself without looking anywhere. I am asking what is wrong WITh assigning the negative charge on N and forming dative bonds with 2 oxygen atoms, """INSTEAD""" of the structure drawn in my book.

Comment: @ShashankSharma What question? $\ce{NO3-}$ means negative charge on the whole ion. Writing $\ce{NO3-}$ does not mean that only oxygen can be assigned a negative sign. The net charge on the ion must be -1. That's all. There is NO strict condition for negative charge to be present only on oxygen atom.

Comment: I can't help now try this en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrate

Comment: Aha! Then you think a little about the electronegativity differences. What does electronegativity mean? Which of the the two $\ce{N}$ and $\ce{O}$ is more electronegative?

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani put that as an answer.

Comment: The octet *is* violated in your proposed structure, by the central nitrogen atom which has nine electrons. A dative bond does not mean an electron is removed from the donating atom; that is ionization. There is in fact no discernible difference between a dative covalent and a normal covalent bond. A dative bond will count as two electrons for each connected atom, just like a regular covalent bond.

Answer (score 2):

As $\ce{O}$ is more electronegative than $\ce{N}$ the $\ce{1-}$ charge in the $\ce{O-N}$ will be on the oxygen. Even if it were to be a dative bond, its donation in an electron pair makes it very easy for oxygen to take. Oxygen is, after all, an oxidising agent.

Comment: Although I now have an answer to my question (from my teacher), your answer seems to be wrong, based on the fact in $\ce{CN-}$, N is more electronegative than C, yet the -1 charge is still on C.

Comment: @Swapnil For $\ce{CN^-}$ it is a different story, note that the -1 on the C allows for both bonding atoms to have a full octet. In the previous example both the O and the N had a full octet already so the extra -1 goes the the electronegative one.